# How do I use the LARGE_INTEGER parameter expected by SetFilePointerEx?

Tags: winapi

I am doing a random file access to write log records in it. Later, I do access the log based on the log number. Using the log number I do calculate the offset of the record and directly access that. The function SetFilePointerEx is used to set the current location in the file and from there I can directly read the record.

The function expects the LARGE_INTEGER as parameter. How do I use LARGE_INTEGER for the SetFilePointerEx function? The req. notes says that the program will be targeted to 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `LARGE_INTEGER li;`, just set `li.QuadPart` to the `LONGLONG` value you need for your file offset and use `li` for the offset argument in the call. Or did I miss something obvious.?

```
LARGE_INTEGER li, lo={0};
li.QuadPart = yourOffsetValue;

SetFilePointerEx(hFile, li, &lo, FILE_BEGIN);
```

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig. That helps... 
Also I can able to write the records at random location. I looked at the Union and got confused. Thanks for the Answer.